# Can we dynamically remove a slide from Carousel in MVC through JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Bootstrap Carousel.This is what I want to achieve:
Sorry for the big post, my intention is to provide more info, so that someone can help me more effectively.

1. Delete a slide(lets say 5th slide) and render(make 'active') the next slide(6th).
2. If the slide I am deleting(5th), is the last in the sequence,then it should redirect to Some specific View(there is a redirect-url property in that button ).
3. If this is the only slide which I am deleting, then it should redirect to some other specific view.

The button(from which the above functionalities are called)are residing in the same slide, which we are to delete and go the next slide/view depending on the conditions mentioned.

This is Code for Carousel:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrevious">@PatientForms.Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNext">@PatientForms.SaveAndNext</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.AppointmentId)
<div id="divPatientFormCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    @for (int slideCount = 0; slideCount < @formCount; slideCount++) {
      if (slideCount == 0) {
        <li data-target="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount" class="active" onclick="SetSaveAndNext()"></li>
      }
      else if (slideCount == formCount - 1) {
        <li data-target="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount" onclick="SetFinish()"></li>
      }
      else {
        <li data-target="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide-to="@slideCount" onclick="SetSaveAndNext()"></li>
      }
    }     
  </ol>
```

And this is how the Wrapper looks like:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @{int noOfForms = 0; string activeClass = string.Empty;}
        @if (Model.DemographicFormData != null && Model.DemographicFormData.DemographicFormId > 0) {
          <div class="item active" id="@Model.DemographicFormData.DemographicFormId">
            @Html.Hidden("formCount", noOfForms)
            <form novalidate method="post" id="frmDemographics+@Model.DemographicFormData.DemographicFormId" data-url='@Url.Action("SaveDemographicForm", "PatientForms")' action="#">
              <div class="row">
                @Html.Partial("DemographicForm", Model.DemographicFormData)
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                  @if (formCount == 1) {
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                      <button id="btnSavedemographicForm" data-navurl="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientForms")" class="btn btn-primary">@PatientForms.Save</button>
                    </div>
                  }
                  <div class="row col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button id="btnDemographicFormSubmit" data-navurl="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientForms")" class="btn btn-primary">@PatientForms.Submit</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-md visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button type="reset" id="btnResetDemographicForm" class="btn btn-primary">@PatientForms.Clear</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

  <br />
        @{ noOfForms = 1;  }
      </div>
    }
    @if (Model.ConsentForms != null && Model.ConsentForms.Any()) {
      foreach (var consentForm in Model.ConsentForms) {
        activeClass = noOfForms == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty;
        <div class="item @activeClass" id="@consentForm.ConsentFormId">
          @Html.Hidden("formCount", noOfForms)
          @{Html.RenderPartial("ConsentForm", consentForm);}
        </div>
          noOfForms++;
      }
      @* Render the Required field if we don't have the intake forms at all *@
      if(Model.Notes == null){
       <button class="btn btn-primary hide" data-url="@Url.Action("RequiredFormFields", "PatientForms", new { patientId = Model.PatientId, appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId })" id="btnLastPage">@PatientForms.Submit</button>
    }
      }
    @if (Model.Notes != null && Model.Notes.Any()) {
      foreach (var note in Model.Notes) {
        activeClass = noOfForms == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty;
        <div class="item @activeClass" id="@note.NoteId" >
          @Html.Hidden("formCount", noOfForms)
          <div class="text-primary" style="text-align: center;">
            <h2>@note.PageName</h2>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="row " style="overflow-x:auto" >
            <div class="col-md-10" style="position:relative;">
              <form novalidate id="frmIntakeForm+@note.NoteId" method="post" data-url='@Url.Action("SaveForms", "PatientForms")' action="#">
                @Html.HiddenFor(item => note.NoteId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(item => note.IsLastNote)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PatientId)
                <div class="row col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                  @Html.Partial("PageControls", note.NoteControls)
                  @{var maxHeight = note.NoteControls.Max(x => x.TopLocation)+400+"px";}
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row" style="margin-top:@maxHeight;position:relative">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          @if (formCount == 1) {
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-primary cancel" data-navurl="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientForms")" id="btnSave">@PatientForms.Save</button>
            </div>
          }
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary cancel " data-url="@Url.Action("SubmitForms", "PatientForms")" data-navurl="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientForms")" id="btnSubmit+@note.NoteId">@PatientForms.Submit</button>
            @if (formCount - 1 == noOfForms) {
            <button class="btn btn-primary hide" data-url="@Url.Action("RequiredFormFields", "PatientForms", new { patientId = Model.PatientId, appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId })" id="btnLastPage">@PatientForms.Submit</button>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
                <br />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
              @if (ViewBag.AskQuestion != null && ViewBag.AskQuestion) {
                <button id="btnAskQuestion" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-url="@Url.Action("SendMessage", "Messages", new { category = @note.PageName, patientId = @note.PatientId, appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId, index = noOfForms })"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> @Message.AskAQuestion</button>
              }
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
              noOfForms++;
      }
    }
  </div>
  <a id="leftChevron" class="left carousel-control hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" style="margin-left:-90px;filter:none" href="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a id="rightChevron" class="right carousel-control hidden-xs hidden-sm  hidden-md hidden-lg" style="margin-right: -90px; filter: none; " href="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do exactly, can you post a js fiddle?

Comment: ok, sorry for that.Probably in JSfiddle this wont go as it has C# code involved.But basically, using JQuery,  I want to delete/remove a specific slide above and render the next slide as 'active'.

Comment: @Maulzal, will you be able to help now?

Comment: Well, my first thoughts are to put your slide objects in an array, and push and pull them in and out when you add / delete, but I'm not sure about your need for making the one after a deleted one "active".. yet..